# CSS Grid Layout (IE support)

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a website partial with CSS grid layout, which needs to work in IE10+ as well. It needs a left column and two right columns.

Layout example:
[image]

CSS:

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#page {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

    -ms-grid-rows: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;

    -ms-grid-columns: 60% 40%;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
}
#page #left {
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
    grid-column: 1;

    -ms-grid-row: 2; 
    grid-row: 2/4;

    -ms-grid-row-span: 2;

    background-color: #ffa08c;

    margin-right: 5px;
}
#page #righttop {
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    grid-column: 2;

    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    grid-row: 1;

    background-color: #ffff64;

    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#page #rightbottom {        
    -ms-grid-column: 2;
    grid-column: 2;

    -ms-grid-row: 2;
    grid-row: 2;

    background-color: #8cffa0;

    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="page">
  <div id="left">
    <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAq1AAAAJGYzMThlNTdiLWQ4YjEtNDFiMi1hNmExLWEzOTZmM2Y2NjMwYg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="righttop">
    <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAq1AAAAJGYzMThlNTdiLWQ4YjEtNDFiMi1hNmExLWEzOTZmM2Y2NjMwYg.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="rightbottom">
    <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAq1AAAAJGYzMThlNTdiLWQ4YjEtNDFiMi1hNmExLWEzOTZmM2Y2NjMwYg.jpg">
  </div>
```

I think I'm almost there but can't get the left column to stretch the height of the both right columns.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Kenvdb/pen/ZvxGry)

Comment: It's not stretching on Chrome at the moment either. You can give `#left` a `grid-row` property of `1/4` -- https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/vpRNGE

Comment: As for IE10, this article might be helpful -->https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and see if it works on your IE (it works on my IE 11). The main changes are using named rows and columns to build the template:

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#page {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    grid-gap: 5px;

    -ms-grid-rows: 
      [top-start] 1fr 
      [top-end] 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 
      [top-start] 1fr 
      [top-end] 1fr;

    -ms-grid-columns: 
      [left-img-start] 3fr 
      [right-img-start] 2fr;
    grid-template-columns: 
      [left-img-start] 3fr 
      [right-img-start] 2fr;
}
#page #left {
    -ms-grid-column: left-img-start;
    grid-column: left-img-start;

    -ms-grid-row: top-start / span 2;
    grid-row: top-start / span 2;

    background-color: #ff0;
}
#page #righttop {
    -ms-grid-column: right-img-start;
    grid-column: right-img-start;
    background-color: #ffff64;
}
#page #rightbottom {        
    background-color: #8cffa0;
}
```

Comment: Hi MattYao, thanks for sharing your solution. Unfortunately, it's not working on my environment (Win 10 Pro + IE11).